# What ranks are possible, and what decides it?

Tags: luigis-mansion-3

Just finished the game, got a B rank, but no explanation of what gave me that rank.

Is it collectibles? Cash in pocket at the end? Number of game overs? Combination of all of the above?

Also, what are the possible ranks? I would guess A through maybe E or F; and maybe a S or even SS rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the other Luigi’s Mansion games, what determines your rank is how much money you have, and only money! You get more money by being more skilled at the game — such as sucking up ghosts in one suck, or by capturing lots of gold ghosts, according to [this article](https://www.usgamer.net/articles/luigis-mansion-3-gold-fastest-ways-to-make-money).

And as for how many ranks there are, there isn’t a definitive answer. But if we’re going to go by past Luigi’s Mansions, it’s gonna be 9 ranks. 'S' being the best and 'H' being the worst, according to [this article](https://www.ign.com/articles/2019/10/28/luigis-mansion-3-guide-how-to-get-rank-s).

Comment: Wonder if collectibles have a value. Pretty sure i ended with about 50k and got b

Comment: From what I read in an article the other day finding all gems and boos is also necessary to get at least an A rank.  But you are saying only money. Are you certain about that?

Comment: This is a good start, but I think this topic needs more research before something can be considered a definitive answer.

Comment: Only A, B, and C have ever been reported for Luigis Mansion 3 as far as I can see, so this answer would seem to be incorrect.