# Does a higher rank change the ending in any way?

Tags: luigis-mansion-3

I've recently played through *Luigi's Mansion 3*. I didn't really care for any Boos, crystals or [money](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/360408/what-ranks-are-possible-and-what-decides-it), and the game awarded me with the **rank B** at the end of the credits scene.

Given that this is my first title in the Mansion's series, I'm not sure whether the credit scene is tied to the rank in any way. **Does a higher rank change the ending scene or any other (post-)game content?** Or is it just fluff and for show in a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much the only thing that you get when you get a higher ranking is a larger mansion (This differently sized mansion is only for cool looks and does not affect the game play in any way) and bragging rights. Here is the criteria for each rank:

1. **Rank A:** 70,000+ dollars at the end of the game.
2. **Rank B:** 60-70,000 dollars at the end of the game.
3. **Rank C:** Anything below 60,000 dollars at the end of the game.

NOTE: Spent money does not count as having the money at the end of the game

I hope this helps :)

Comment: It's been a while. What do you mean by "larger mansion"?

Comment: Pretty much at the end, the professor, Luigi, and the ghosts rebuild the mansion. The more money you collect, the bigger that rebuilt mansion will be.

Comment: There's no S-rank?

Comment: Nope, there are only the 3 ranks listed above.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between the three different ranks is in the final cut scene, the mansion you create is bigger the better your rank is. Your rank is decided by the amount of money you collect at the end. Here's a YouTube link to show you the different cut scenes you get depending on the amount of money you gather.